# How to open app in recovery mode?

Tags: macos

When I was in recovery mode to change a password I forgot, I got distracted by trying to open an app in recovery mode.

I tried /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/Google\ Chrome/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome, but I got this result:

Killed: 9.

I am running on a 2018 15-inch macbook pro. My OS is currently macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

Recovery is not a full operating system. It's not designed to be able to run apps - nor is it capable of doing so. It can only run apps/utilities designed specifically to run in that environment.

As such, it can run a limited version of Safari, specifically designed to run in such circumstances.

Around a decade or more ago [2010-ish], a determined hacker managed to get a fully bootable running copy of Snow Leopard and a good collection of Mac 'fixit' tools onto a 4GB USB stick [Snow Leo 911 Pro for those who remember back that far]. As far as I'm aware, it's never been done since. With the advent of Internet Recovery, SSDs & fast external drives it no longer seems worth the effort. Tech Tool Pro can now also make this type of recovery drive as a hidden partition on any disk, to which you can manually add tools.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will keep investigating this, would you happen to know what is killing the process and how?

Comment: It's likely to be the vestigial OS itself, issuing a pre-emptive kill to prevent a million other errors as it tries to launch into an environment it simply cannot run in.

Comment: Ok. So I cant kill whatever process is killing google chrome?

Comment: What do you hope to gain? It will not run in Recovery. Safari will. Use that.